# How do I play late game Irelia?

Tags: league-of-legends

How can I be an affective player with Irelia in late-game and teamfights? When chasing down enemies or 1v1'ing I feel like she excels throughout the whole game. During teamfights, however I target the squishy champs, and I usually kill one before I die. Sometimes if I don't get a kill or without me there after I die, my team loses the teamfights, which often costs us a few towers or even the game.

I feel like with Irelia I'm doing really well and helping me team win, but as soon as we hit teamfighting phase I just hit a wall, and I'm either trading 1:1 or dying more than I kill. I feel that I should be playing this way since Irelia is an assassin, sorta, but I feel like I'm not benefiting from it late game. So how can I play her better during late-game and teamfighting? All help and tips is appreciated!

Comment: im no expert,but i think leaning towards a more tank orientated build is best for her :p

Answer (score 2):

The thing with Irelia is she doesn't really have an early, mid, or late game unfortunately. The good thing about Irelia is she is incredibly versatile in how you can build her. A lot of complaints revolve around how many times she has been Nerfed, when she probably just needs a complete overhaul.

Your priority with Irelia should be either jumping the enemy carries or peeling for you carries. With the way you build and your cc this should be relatively easy unless your enemy is really fed. Being that Irelia has no initiate you shouldn't be the first person to fight, you should be sitting back for just a second to assess the situation and determine where you are needed most, as in peeling or killing.

You should go teleport/ignite or teleport/flash, allowing you to split push or counter gank for your carries.

A thing to keep in mind is Irelia is a Bruiser, so building Tanky/Damage items and masteries/runes is the best choice. Go MR Glyphs, Armor Seals, AD Marks or AS Marks and AD Quints or AS Quints seems to be the typical trend with Irelia.

Your early game goals should be boots and Phlage and stinger (Vs AD) or Wit's End (Vs AP). Next you wanna get Frozen Mallet for nice tankiness and the nice slow. Get Zephyr as soon after, giving you the AS and Movement Speed and no one will escape you. Stick to Beserker's for the AS but if you fall behind go Mercury treads or Ninja tabi. Couple other items would be Randuin's Omen, Guardian Angel, atma's impaler, warmog's, Maw of malimortus.

This build is a very tanky/Damage build, if you aren't already building this change and you'll probably see a performance increase. If you are building this, look at how your playing. Are you getting a lot of CS are you overextending are you roaming when you should be. So many things come into play after you've locked in a decent build.

Comment: Maybe the problem was that I was going in to early? Now that I think of it, I would kind a just jump ahead of my team and try and kill someone. Also, I build everything the same, except Zephyr. I build botrk instead, but do you think that is a bit of overkill on sustain along with her hiten style? What is your opinion on building that instead of zephyr?

Comment: @Jonny Late game is determined by Early game so it could be that. And initiating as Irelia is Suicide. I would say Botrk isn't a bad thing to build just unnecessary. she already has a sustain, and if you play right thats all the sustain you should need. and most ppl build it for dmg not lifesteal.

Comment: Irelia's passive should provide enough Tenacity when surrounded by many enemy champions. You don't need Zephyr in teamfights, unless you're facing Amumu + Leona + Ashe + Zyra + Kennen. Focus on DPS and HP/armor/MR.

Comment: So I've tried the build, and it seems better, just every game I get, we have leavers or feeders that cost me the game. But, regardless, the build is working better for the most part. What do you recommend now that phage has a different passive? I was thinking of just sticking with phage and bUilding trinity force, since I feel like it is better with an assassin-ish, chase em down, play style. Your opinion?

Comment: @Jonny amazing job figuring that out, its actually a change i have made as well. Trinity Force is now a very practical item for every bruiser. The thing to keep in mind is I have never played Irelia so that build is something I took watching other Irelia's and looking up different builds online for you. After studing her play style and what made her shine the most is how i came up with a decent answer. the great thing about Irelia is she is one of the best CSers in the game so you'll have plenty of chances to make tweaks to her build.

Comment: @Jonny as a bruiser I go very straight chase um down/tanky builds with just enough damage to be formittable. Swiftness boots/boots of mobility along with frozen mallet and trinity force as my starting items is a pretty basic start that I have great success with. just recently went 6-2 wins to loses (that includes one mid game.(look yourself "Paralyitc" on LOLking.com (or something))).